# Deleting duplicates in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-delete

In MSSQL TABLE I have 3 columns.

```
ID (IDENTITY), KeptValue(NVARCHAR), SPENT(MONEY).
```

I have multiple `KeptValue`s that are duplicated. I need to delete all duplicates and keep 1. But I need to keep the one with the greatest spent.
I have 2 views created. a list of the duplicated kept values `VW_DUPLICATE1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
delete t1
from your_table t1
left join  
(
   select keptvalue, max(spent) as mSpent
   from your_table
   group by keptvalue

) t2 on t1.keptvalue = t2.keptvalue and t1.spent = t2.mSpent
where t2.mSpent is null
```

Comment: id is not mentioned in group by it throws error "Column 'id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Comment: @bvr: Of course. I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to delete by specific `KepValue` keeping the highest `SPENT`.

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE SPENT < (SELECT MAX(SPENT) FROM your_table WHERE KeptValue='your_value') AND KeptValue='your_value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT Id FROM (
        SELECT 
            Id
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KeptValue ORDER BY SPENT DESC) AS [ItemNumber]
        FROM 
            tbl
    ) a WHERE ItemNumber > 1 
)
```

Comment: @Julian Michael Mostert try this it gives your req output

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Create table #temp ( ID int, KeptValue NVARCHAR(20) , SPENT numeric(18,3))

INSERT INTO #temp select 1,'KeptValue1', 20
INSERT INTO #temp select 2,'KeptValue1', 21
INSERT INTO #temp select 3,'KeptValue2', 22
INSERT INTO #temp select 4,'KeptValue2', 20
INSERT INTO #temp select 5,'KeptValue2', 20
INSERT INTO #temp select 6,'KeptValue3', 20
INSERT INTO #temp select 7,'KeptValue3', 23
INSERT INTO #temp select 8,'KeptValue3', 24
INSERT INTO #temp select 9,'KeptValue4', 28
INSERT INTO #temp select 10,'KeptValue4', 23
INSERT INTO #temp select 11,'KeptValue5', 24
INSERT INTO #temp select 12,'KeptValue6', 28

select * FROM #temp 

DELETE 
FROM #temp 
WHERE ID 
in(
    select ID from  
                    (SELECT Id, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KeptValue order by SPENT desc)) as R 
                    from #temp
                    ) as RowsNm
    WHERE R >1)

select * from #temp 


drop table #temp
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achive this by doing a `group by` KeptValue and a `max` aggregate on Spent

Comment: I think he means to delete the duplicate and not just ignore them by using a `Group By`.

Comment: Thanks, yes maybe i didnt make this clear. It's good to know why you get a downvote, so you can learn for next time!